# Joining MySQL results from the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm proficient with joining tables in mySQL, but I'm having trouble with joining results from the SAME table. I'm creating a folder structure in PHP where a folder has an ID, a parent ID, a random-string ID, and a label.

My DB looks like:

```
| id | parent_id | uniq   | label
---------------------------------
| 1  | 0         | w2d4f6 | dir 1
| 2  | 1         | h9k3h7 | dir 2
```

The front end uses the `uniq` var to identify a folder. So In the DB you can see that if I am opening the folder `dir 1`, the folder `dir 2` will be inside it, since `dir 2` has `dir 1`'s ID as its parent.

Still with me?

```
|- dir 1
|  + dir 2
```

The folder `dir 1` is identified by its uniq string, so `w2d4f6`. So what I'm wanting to do is:

1. Get the parent ID of the record that has `uniq='w2d4f6'`
2. The parent ID is `1`
3. Look for records where `parent_id=1`

I know this is totally wrong, and I think I should be using `JOIN` but I tried the following without success.

`SELECT folders.label,folders.parent_id FROM folders WHERE folders.uniq='w2d4f6' AND folders.id=folders.parent_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the children of a folder:

```
select b.label, b.parent_id
from folders a, folders b
where a.uniq = 'w2d4f6' AND b.parent_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you already have the parent data and just want to request the child data by the uniq value of the parent:

```
SELECT label, parent_id FROM folders WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM folders WHERE uniq='w2d4f6')
```

Comment: I see that the code from jspcal gives the same result ;)

Comment: Does this perform two queries though?

Comment: It seems like both queries do that if I use EXPLAIN on them.
Edit: both queries run around 0,015s for a table I have.